# How do you generate multiple dropdown list boxes in UI App

Tags: javascript, forms, google-apps-script

I have been working with the sample code to allow a user to submit a photo in a google form for update to Google spreadsheet.
I am working with the original code by Serge Insas that I was able to get to work exactly how he intended it to work.
Now I'm trying to work with it to allow for my needs which is simply to have more than one drop down list, I need to capture more information than what the original code allowed for.
I am very new to this and doing most by trial and error.
I can get the form to display with two list boxes but the drop down list of both of them is the same (List1)

Here is the code I've modified, it will post what is selected in the second list box but I need the items from list2 to show up instead.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

```
var submissionSSKey = '0ArbqJejC7zBydGNUbVpwd2hrQ3RFY3VxZ0RCeU5aV3c';
var docurl = 'https://docs.google.com/document/d/13FWMTtzprlhN73cMp73zPtunsOcoAFO5PCROp1PHiv4/'
var listitems = ['Select a category', 'LKQ', 'AM', 'OEM']
var listitems2 = ['Select a category', 'Wrong Part', 'Poor Fit', 'Poor Quality']
var Panelstyle = {
    'background': '#dddddd',
    'padding': '40px',
    'borderStyle': 'solid',
    'borderWidth': '10PX',
    'borderColor': '#bbbbbb'
}

function doGet() {
    var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Parts Return Reasons').setStyleAttribute('padding', '50PX');
    var panel = app.createFormPanel().setStyleAttributes(Panelstyle).setPixelSize(400, 200);
    var title = app.createHTML('<B>PartsReturnReasons</B>').setStyleAttribute('color', 'grey').setStyleAttribute('fontSize', '25PX');
    var grid = app.createGrid(7, 2).setId('grid');
    var list1 = app.createListBox().setName('list1').setWidth('130');
    for (var i in listitems) {
        list1.addItem(listitems[i])
    }
    var list2 = app.createListBox().setName('list2').setWidth('130');
    for (var i in listitems2) {
        list2.addItem(listitems[i])
    }
    var Textbox1 = app.createTextBox().setWidth('150px').setName('TB1');
    var email = app.createTextBox().setWidth('150px').setName('mail');
    var upLoad = app.createFileUpload().setName('uploadedFile');
    var submitButton = app.createSubmitButton('<B>Submit</B>');
    var warning = app.createHTML('Please fill in all fields').setStyleAttribute('background', '#bbbbbb').setStyleAttribute('fontSize', '18px');
    //file upload
    var cliHandler2 = app.createClientHandler()
        .validateLength(Textbox1, 1, 40).validateNotMatches(list1, 'Select a category').validateEmail(email).validateNotMatches(upLoad, 'FileUpload')
        .forTargets(submitButton).setEnabled(true)
        .forTargets(warning).setHTML('Now you can submit your form').setStyleAttribute('background', '#99FF99').setStyleAttribute('fontSize', '12px');

    //Grid layout of items on form
    grid.setWidget(0, 1, title)
        .setText(1, 0, 'Category')
        .setWidget(1, 1, list1.addClickHandler(cliHandler2))
        .setText(2, 0, 'Reason')
        .setWidget(2, 1, list2.addClickHandler(cliHandler2))
        .setText(3, 0, 'Name')
        .setWidget(3, 1, Textbox1.addClickHandler(cliHandler2))
        .setText(4, 0, 'Email')
        .setWidget(4, 1, email)
        .setText(5, 0, 'Image File')
        .setWidget(5, 1, upLoad.addChangeHandler(cliHandler2))
        .setWidget(6, 0, submitButton)
        .setWidget(6, 1, warning);

    var cliHandler = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(warning).setHTML('<B>PLEASE WAIT WHILE THE FILE IS UPLOADING<B>').setStyleAttribute('background', 'yellow');
    submitButton.addClickHandler(cliHandler).setEnabled(false);
    panel.add(grid);
    app.add(panel);
    return app;
}


function doPost(e) {
    var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
    var ListVal1 = e.parameter.list1;
    var ListVal2 = e.parameter.list2;
    var textVal = e.parameter.TB1;
    var Email = e.parameter.mail;
    var fileBlob = e.parameter.uploadedFile;
    var blob = fileBlob.setContentTypeFromExtension()
    var img = DocsList.createFile(blob);
    try {
        var folder = DocsList.getFolder('photos');
    } catch (e) {
        DocsList.createFolder('photos');
        var folder = DocsList.getFolder('photos')
    }
    img.addToFolder(folder);
    img.removeFromFolder(DocsList.getRootFolder());
    var weight = parseInt(img.getSize() / 1000);
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(submissionSSKey).getSheetByName('Sheet1');
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    var targetRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1, 1, 5).setValues([
        [ListVal1, ListVal2, textVal, Email, "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=" + img.getId()]
    ]);
    var imageInsert = sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 5).setFormula('=image("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=' + img.getId() + '")');
    sheet.setRowHeight(lastRow + 1, 80);
    var GDoc = DocumentApp.openByUrl(docurl)
    GDoc.appendTable([
        ['Category : ' + ListVal1, ListVal2, 'Name : ' + textVal, 'Email : ' + Email]
    ])
    var inlineI = GDoc.appendImage(img);
    var width = inlineI.getWidth();
    var newW = width;
    var height = inlineI.getHeight();
    var newH = height;
    var ratio = width / height;
    Logger.log('w=' + width + 'h=' + height + ' ratio=' + ratio);
    if (width > 640) {
        newW = 640;
        newH = parseInt(newW / ratio);
    }
    inlineI.setWidth(newW).setHeight(newH)
    GDoc.appendParagraph('IMAGE size : ' + width + ' x ' + height + ' (eventually) resized to ' + newW + ' x ' + newH + ' for PREVIEW (' + weight + ' kB)   ');
    GDoc.appendHorizontalRule();
    GDoc.saveAndClose();
    app.add(app.createLabel('Thank you for submitting'));
    return app;
}
```

Comment: Please specify what specific problem you are having and what you have tried so far

Comment: The problem is this: The displayed form originally allowed for One list box which was var listitems. I can change what items show up in that list box easily enough but I want to have two seperate list boxes each with their own set of drop down items. As for what I've tried the code above is how I've tried to add a second list box. I'm sure the doPost will have a problem posting the data properly once I've got the second list box working as this whole code was originally built to handle only one list box.

Answer (score 2):

You made a simple typo in your code.

```
for (var i in listitems2) { list2.addItem(listitems2[i])
```

You have to take items for list in the right source array